# when hover on line from text or articles While reading chang background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

It is well known that the article consists of several lines.
To enable the reader to distinguish the line that reads it , so i want when hover on line from text or articles While reading change background color?
for know all text it between `<p></p>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with javascript

add jQuery 1.9.1

JSFIDDLE Example Is [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9xe533yb/1/)

Javascript code :

```
var $div = $("<div>"), 
    $marker = $("<div>"),
    adder = [],
    $p = $("p"),
    $line = $("<span>").appendTo($marker),
    lastWord = '';

$marker.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '100%'}).appendTo("body");

$p.text().split(/\s/).forEach(function (elem) {
$line.text($line.text() + elem + ' ');
if ($line.width() > $p.width()) {
    $line.text(function (_, text) {
        return text.slice(0, text.lastIndexOf(elem));
    });

    $line.appendTo($div);
    console.log($line.text());
    $line = $("<span>");
    $line.text(' ' + elem).appendTo($marker);
    console.log($marker.html() + "END");
  } 
});
$div.append($marker.html());
$p.html($div.html());
$div.remove();
$marker.remove();
```